# Invalid method declaration; return type requred?

Tags: java

I am getting an 'invalid method declaration; return type required at this section:

```
public updateFrequency(int frequence) {
    frequence = frequency++;
    return frequence;
}
```

full code below

```
public class Node {
String number; //node data
Node left;  //points to the left sub-tree
Node right; //points to the right sub-tree
int frequency;

public Node(String s) {
    number = s;
    left = null;  //set value to null because it is empty
    right = null; //set value to null because it is empty
    frequency = 1; //starting frequency value
}

public void add(String value) {
    if (left == null) {
        left = new Node(value);
    }
    else if (right == null) {
        right = new Node(value);
    }
    else {
        if (countChildNodes(left) <= countChildNodes(right)) {
            left.add(value);
        }
        else {
            right.add(value);
        }
    }
}

public int countChildNodes(Node node) {
    int count = 0;
    if(node != null) {
        count = 1 + countChildNodes(node.getLeft()) + countChildNodes(node.getRight());
    }
    return count;
}

public updateFrequency(int frequence) {
    frequence = frequency++;
    return frequence;
}

public void increaseFrequency() {  //increases the frequency of string occurences
    frequency++;
}

public int getFrequency() { //returns frequency of given string
    return frequency;
} 

public Node getRight() {
    return right;
}

public Node getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

}

Could anyone point out my error? My other classes are named TreeDemo and BinarySearchTree but I'm not sure if that matters.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to say what variable type this method is returning.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the return type specified in your method. If you are returning a String, you can say String in the declaration. You can return almost any type.

You code will look like this:

```
public int updateFrequency(int frequence)
{
   frequence = frequency++;
   return frequence;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a return type for the method.

```
public int updateFrequency(int frequence) {
    frequence = frequency++;
    return frequence;
}
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: "return type required". Your method needs a return type. `public int updateFrequency(int frequency){`

Answer (score 0):

`updateFrequency` has no return type. You can specify it like:

```
public int updateFrequency(int frequence) {
    frequence = frequency++;
    return frequence;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the argument `frequence`?

Comment: @pbabcdefp The OP listed it, so I assume he wants it. Ask the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For any instance method which is not a constructor, you have to declare a return type. In your case, since you are returning an int, your method should look like `public int updateFrequency(int frequence) {`.

By the way, in your implementation, the `frequence` variable can be local to the `updateFrequency()` method. You don't need to pass it as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Currently you don't have a return type specified. So, if you are trying to return the `frequency` value of the method, you'd do:

```
public int updateFrequency(int frequence) {
    this.frequence = frequency++;
    return this.frequence;
}
```

If you don't want to return a value, you still need to add the `void` return type and do this:

```
public void updateFrequency(int frequence) {
    this.frequence = frequency++;
}
```

Also, since `frequency` is an instance variable, you can do this:

```
public void updateFrequency() {
    this.frequency++;
}
```